# Change one column value for a specific group of variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataset:

```
help <- data.frame(id = c(rep(5, times = 5), rep(12, times = 3), rep(33, times = 2), rep(54, times = 3), rep(66, times = 4)),
                   ob = c(rep(1, times = 5), rep(0, times = 3), rep(1, times = 2), rep(0, times =3), rep(1, times =4)))
```

I am trying to change only the values for id = 5 and 66 from 1 to 0 so the df looks like this:

```
    id ob
1   5  0
2   5  0
3   5  0
4   5  0
5   5  0
6  12  0
7  12  0
8  12  0
9  33  1
10 33  1
11 54  0
12 54  0
13 54  0
14 66  0
15 66  0
16 66  0
17 66  0
```

I have attempted:

```
change <- c(5, 66)
mutate(help, ob = ifelse(xor(id %in% change), ob == 0, 1))
```

But I keep hitting errors and I don't want to change the values of any other id, only the ones specified. I could do this the long way by filtering out and replacing and joining back in, but guessing there is a quicker solution.  Any help would be great.

Comment: `replace(help$ob, help$id %in% c(5, 66), 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `%in%` to create a logical index and then based on that assign the values of 'ob' to 0

```
help$ob[help$id %in% c(5, 66)] <- 0
```

---

If we are using `ifelse`, then

```
help$ob <- with(help, ifelse(id %in% c(5, 66), 0, ob))
```

NOTE: Both of these are `base R` methods

Answer (score 0):

We can do it also the `data.table` way:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(help)
help[id %in% c(5, 66), ob := 0]
```